# Proving a certain vector is in $B_r(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm trying to prove that if $x = (x_1,\cdots, x_n)\in B_r(a)$, and $y = (y_1,\cdots, y_n)\in B_r(a)$, then $z(j) = (y_1,\cdots, y_j,x_{j+1},\cdots, x_n)\in B_r(a)$ as well for all $j$. I'm not even sure if it's true, it might not be, I haven't tested it with many input vectors, but from the tests I have done it seems reasonable enough. I attempted to show it by induction, assuming
$$
(x_1-a_1)^2+\cdots + (x_n-a_n)^2\le r^2 \\
(y_1-a_1)^2+\cdots + (y_n-a_n)^2\le r^2 \\
(y_1-a_1)^2+\cdots+(y_{k-1}-a_{k-1})^2+(x_k-a_k)^2+\cdots+(x_n-a_n)^2\le r^2
$$
and arriving at $(y_1-a_1)^2+\cdots+(y_k-a_k)^2+(x_{k+1}-a_{k+1})^2+\cdots+(x_n-a_n)^2\le r^2$. We can rewrite the sum up to $y_k$ as

$$
((y_1-a_1)^2+\cdots+(y_{k-1}-a_{k-1})^2+(x_k-a_k)^2+\cdots+(x_n-a_n)^2) + (y_k-a_k)^2-(x_k-a_k)^2 \le r^2+(y_k-a_k)^2-(x_k-a_k)^2
$$
but this is where I get stuck. I can't see how to incorporate the other assumptions into the inductive step.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's basically not true. In ${\bf{R}}^{2}$, consider the unit ball, put $x=(1/10,9/10)$ and $y=(9/10,1/10)$, joining them as the way you introduced, $z=(9/10,9/10)$ does not lie in the ball.